# QGIS label priority settings

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a table with a lot of place names. There are much too many names for all of them to be shown on the print composer map.  Some names are important, and in the column fontsize these have a bigger font size number (for instance 270). I want to prioritize bigger font size names over smaller font size names. So I go to Layer Properties -> Labels -> Placement -> and in Priority chose a data defined override by selecting the field fontsize .

Should this work? It does not give rational results, as some smaller labels are still shown instead of bigger ones.

Qgis version 2.18.7

Comment: How about using `Label z-index` along with associated `data defined override` to assign the font size as control?

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable completely from showing small labels, you can use `Properties -> Labels -> Render -> Show labels` and write the following formula:

```
CASE WHEN 
"fontsize" <> 270 THEN NULL
Else "Name"
END
```

Where `"Name"` is the field name that contains the names you want to show.

[image]

Do not forget to use `Label with` `"Name"` or the suitable field name that shows the names.

In the following example, I am showing only the Ids that their font size bigger than 50 stored in a field name `"Num"`

[image]

Comment: Thank yoy @ahmadhanb , I do need to show also small labels if there is space enough for them, but I need big labels to always be prioritized over smaller ones.

Comment: @BenjaminDonner How do you define the "enough space"? I think the spaces among the labels are different.

Comment: @ahmadhandb, preferably:

- no labels should go on top of eachother. If they would do this, omit showing smaller size labels (id "fontsize" has a smaller number than the other label)
- no labels should go on top of point symbols in the layer "symbology".